# quanteda: Count number of edges for each node in a network plot

Tags: r, quanteda, network-analysis

I have a network plot computed through the `textplot_network()` function of `quanteda` package. For a minimal, please refer to the official `quanteda` website [here](https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/twitter.html).
What I am reporting below is just a copy-paste of what you can find in the link.

```
library(quanteda)
load("data/data_corpus_tweets.rda")
tweet_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_tweets, remove_punct = TRUE)
tag_dfm <- dfm_select(tweet_dfm, pattern = ("#*"))
toptag <- names(topfeatures(tag_dfm, 50))
topgat_fcm <- fcm_select(tag_fcm, pattern = toptag)
textplot_network(topgat_fcm, min_freq = 0.1, edge_alpha = 0.8, edge_size = 5)
```

The resulting network plot is the following:

[image]

How do I calculate the number of edges for each of the node rendered in the plot? If I use the function `topfeatures()` applied over the `fcm` object `topgat_fcm` I obtain the top hubs of the network which are the counts of the co-occurrences detected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of edges for any node will be the number of cells in the upper triangle, excluding the diagonal (since a feature's co-occurrence with another instance of itself in a document does not produce an "edge" in a plot).

Let's approach this from a simpler example.  I'll define a very simple three-document structure with a six word types.

```r
library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 1.4.0
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
txt <- c("a b b c", "b d d e", "a e f f")
fcmat <- fcm(txt)
fcmat
## Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 6 by 6 features.
## 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "fcm"
##         features
## features a b c d e f
##        a 0 2 1 0 1 2
##        b 0 1 2 2 1 0
##        c 0 0 0 0 0 0
##        d 0 0 0 1 2 0
##        e 0 0 0 0 0 2
##        f 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Here, "a" has four edges, with "b", "c", "e", and "f".  "b" has three edges, with "c", "d", and "e" (excluding "b"s co-occurrence with itself, in the first document).

To get the counts, we can just sum the cells that are non-zero, which can happen using `rowSums()` or if you transpose the matrix, the equivalent function for computing "document" frequency (although here, the features are the "documents").

Excluding self-edges, we can verify these edges by looking at the network plot for this fcm.

```r
rowSums(fcmat > 0)
## a b c d e f 
## 4 4 0 2 1 1
docfreq(t(fcmat))
## a b c d e f 
## 4 4 0 2 1 1

textplot_network(fcmat)
```

[image]

To exclude the self-edge counts, we need to zero the diagonal.  Currently, this will drop the class definition on the fcm, which means we will not be able to use it in `textplot_network()`, but we can still use our `rowSums()` approach to get the edge counts by node, providing the answer to your question.

```r
diag(fcmat) <- 0
rowSums(fcmat > 0)
## a b c d e f 
## 4 3 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll do the job.